# how to change a while sql query loop into an array loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i record number of queries of my website and in page the below script runs , 40 extra queries added to page .

how can  I change this sql connection into a propper and light one

```
    function tree_set($index)
    {
        //global $menu; Remove this.
        $q=mysql_query("select id,name,parent from cats where parent='$index'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($q) === 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // User $tree instead of the $menu global as this way there shouldn't be any data duplication
        $tree = $index > 0 ? '<ul>' : ''; // If we are on index 0 then we don't need the enclosing ul
        while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            $subFileCount=mysql_query("select id,name,parent from cats where parent='{$arr['id']}'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($subFileCount) > 0)
            {
                $class = 'folder';
            }
            else
            {
                $class = 'file';
            }

            $tree .= '<li>';
            $tree .= '<span class="'.$class.'">'.$arr['name'].'</span>';
            $tree .=tree_set("".$arr['id']."");
            $tree .= '</li>'."\n";
        }
        $tree .= $index > 0 ? '</ul>' : ''; // If we are on index 0 then we don't need the enclosing ul

        return $tree;
    }

//variable $menu must be defined before the function call
$menu = '....<ul id="browser" class="filetree">'."\n";
$menu .= tree_set(0);
$menu .= '</ul>';

echo $menu;
```

i heard , this can be done by changing it into an array , but i don't know how to do so

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested code):

```
function tree_set($index)
{
    //global $menu; Remove this.
    $q=mysql_query("select id,name,parent from cats where parent='$index'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q) === 0)
        return;

    $cats = array();
    $cat_ids = array();

    while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
       $id = intval($arr['id']);
       $cats[$id] = $arr;
    }

    $subFilesCountQuery="select parent,count(*) as subFileCount from cats where parent=".
                   join(" OR parent=",array_keys($cats))." GROUP BY parent";

    $subFileCountResult=mysql_query($subFilesCountQuery);

    while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($subFileCountResult))
    {
       $id = intval($arr['parent']);
       $cats[$id]['subFileCount'] = $arr['subFileCount'];
    }

    // If we are on index 0 then we don't need the enclosing ul
    $tree = $index > 0 ? '<ul>' : ''; 
    foreach($cats as $id => $cat)
    {
        if($cat['subFileCount'] > 0)
            $class = 'folder';
        else
            $class = 'file';

        $tree .= '<li>';
        $tree .= '<span class="'.$class.'">'.$arr['name'].'</span>';
        $tree .=tree_set("".$arr['id']."");
        $tree .= '</li>'."\n";
    }
    $tree .= $index > 0 ? '</ul>' : '';
```

What I'm doing is two queries: One to fetch all the categories (your original first query) followed by a second query to fetch all the subcategory counts in one fell swoop. I am also storing all categories in an array which you can loop through, rather than displaying as you fetch from the database.

Comment: Thanks man , but after executing your code , appache stop working because of overflow of queries

Comment: @Mac: Sorry, I had a bug, please [see the changes I made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2877867/revisions) and let me know if that fixes the error.

Comment: @Mac: OH. Silly me, I just realized your algorithm is recursive. My answer is completely wrong... Please acknowledge that you saw this comment, because I want to delete this answer.

Comment: @josh thanks again for your try ,hope to find an answer for this very important question

Comment: @Mac: I'm trying to think of a way to do this in as few queries as possible. What I have would be an improvement but needs more work.

Comment: josh i think i find it myself , by changing your codes , now just few queries used , and everything is fine , and problem is in style part .

the only modification i did , was changing subFileCount into id , becuase i couldnt get why you used subFileCount for count and fetching  , i would be glad if you write a simpler and better one

Comment: @Mac: Sure. I'll be able to clean this answer up a bit tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by copying your data out into an array, and then using that copy: i.e.

```
while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $results[] = $arr;
    }
```

later on, you then do whatever op you want on $results

The main problem with your code is you are mixing your display logic all in with your SQL query.

Comment: i don't get it , would you mind updating your answer with a more complete code ?!
after defining $result[] what should i do ?!

Answer (score -1):

Select whole tree in single query, like "select id,name,parent from cats". Iterate on result, build array in PHP that will represent your tree, then draw HTML using array as source